# Topojson properties field, how do I show all proprieties in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I get to point where I read the topojson file with no errors but the problem is it shows only one property with one path, my topojson file looks like the sample below.
What I am doing wrong ?

```
createMap("QasabatAmmanTempWithoutMadina.json");

function createMap(topojsonFile) {
    d3.json(topojsonFile, function(error, tj) {
    svg.selectAll("path").remove();

        //console.log(key in tj.objects);

        for(key in tj.objects) { features = tj.objects[key];console.log(tj.objects[key]); }
        console.log(features);
        var estados = topojson.feature(tj, features);
            console.log(estados)
        var b = path.bounds(estados);
        var s = 0.95/ Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height);
        var t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

        projection
            .scale(s)
            .translate(t);

        g.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(tj, features).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "feature");
            //.on("click", click);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(tj, features, function(a,b) { return a !== b; }))
            .attr("class", "mesh")
            .attr("d", path);
    });
}
```

Json:

```
{ "type":"Topology","arcs":[[[5629,4900],[26,-20],[21,-38],[-19,-32],[-11,-49],[-40,-82],[-44,-37],[-69,-61],[-53,-23],[-57,-10],[-74,3],[78,32],[78,30],[66,20],[84,6],[39,-14],[31,-58],[43,-68],[44,-36],[33,-30],[43,-37],[52,-47],[57,-40],[43,-36],[47,-16],[47,-18],[68,-6],[72,-6],[65,-4],[74,0]],[[4419,5688],[-31,4],[-113,106],[-12,29],[-20,25],[-27,16],[-38,5],[-171,-8],[-232,76],[-31,-61],[80,-4],[164,-72],[17,1],[180,-67],[27,-23],[34,-17],[36,-32],[24,-34],[9,-38],[4,-29],[6,-29],[6,-31],[-8,-18],[15,-44],[-8,5],[-32,16],[-14,7],[-41,-3],[-36,-13],[-24,-10],[-19,-11],[-24,-3],[-42,14],[-34,10],[-39,10],[-40,20],[-21,18],[-15,19],[-12,27],[-10,17],[-16,18],[-24,5],[-25,-1],[-22,-2],[-24,-18],[20,5],[28,-10],[19,-11],[15,-14],[11,-14],[-5,-20],[-53,32],[-98,-36],[-245,72],[-43,36],[-94,62],[-157,28],[-153,54],[-100,83],[-35,4],[-86,-21],[-63,7],[-55,1],[-98,4],[-101,24],[-72,28],[-36,11],[-28,11],[-15,3],[-98,-6],[-66,1],[-29,9],[-58,26],[-58,37],[-74,65],[-46,62],[-45,84],[-47,136],[-30,135],[-6,69],[6,61],[24,138],[64,122],[77,111],[159,158],[258,228],[68,59],[98,62],[61,25],[80,11],[129,-8],[47,10],[58,23],[99,47],[51,29],[85,58],[95,62],[42,21],[103,39],[193,62],[-26,-196],[3,-134],[0,-57],[5,-114],[-4,-137],[-12,-58],[0,-43],[34,-103],[53,-144],[57,-74],[59,-52],[163,-104],[39,-47],[69,-67],[35,-54],[7,-41],[-32,-103],[1,-20],[35,-121],[16,-29],[87,-83],[24,-15],[26,-2],[30,15],[13,-37],[39,-38],[4,-23],[49,-128],[-3,-30],[19,-46],[17,-70]]],
  "transform": {
    "scale": [0.000012395198638604345,0.000011753131339408293],
    "translate": [35.86398878517448,31.89607962076447]
  },
  "objects": {
    "Zahran_Trusted": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        { "arcs": [[0]],
          "type": "Polygon", 
          "properties": { "Level": 3, "Name_1": "Amman", "Name_2": "Qasabat Amman", "Name_3": "Zahran" }
        }
      ]
    },
    "YarmukAmman_Trusted": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        { "arcs": [[1]],
          "type": "Polygon", 
          "properties": { "Level": 3, "Name_1": "Amman", "Name_2": "Qasabat Amman", "Name_3": "Yarmuk Amman" }
        }
      ]
    },
    "RasAlEin_Trusted": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        { "arcs": [[2]],
          "type": "Polygon",
          "properties":{"Name_1":"Amman", "Name_2": "Qasabat Amman", "Name_3": "Ras Al Ein" } }
      ]
    },
    "BadrAmman_Trusted": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        { "arcs": [[3]],
          "type": "Polygon", 
          "properties": { "Level": 3, "Name_1": "Amman", "Name_2": "Qasabat Amman", "Name_3": "Badr Amman" }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Abdali_Trusted": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        { "arcs": [[4]],
          "type": "Polygon", 
          "properties": { "Level": 3, "Name_1": "Amman", "Name_2": "Qasabat Amman", "Name_3": "Abdali" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRU0k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tight, but I got a (very very) simplified topojson of what I assume is your source data.

Strictly speaking, as I understand your question:

> How do I show all properties of all topojson features

You can achieve this by using d3.map. If seeking it for all features you can nest a d3.map inside a d3.map - the first one pulls up each feature, the second each key and value:

```js
var data = {"type":"Topology","arcs":[[[239,1180],[-10,8]],[[229,1188],[-16,23]],[[213,1211],[41,-18]],[[254,1193],[-15,-13]],[[284,1115],[26,23]],[[310,1138],[26,-13]],[[336,1125],[3,-15]],[[339,1110],[-19,-10]],[[320,1100],[-41,1]],[[279,1101],[5,14]],[[277,1310],[-9,0]],[[268,1310],[1,11]],[[269,1321],[3,4]],[[272,1325],[5,-15]],[[228,887],[18,0]],[[246,887],[15,-19]],[[261,868],[-39,-39]],[[222,829],[6,58]],[[324,1034],[-8,-3]],[[316,1031],[-23,24]],[[293,1055],[37,24]],[[330,1079],[20,-21]],[[350,1058],[-26,-24]],[[237,1145],[-11,-1]],[[226,1144],[13,36]],[[239,1180],[31,0]],[[270,1180],[-33,-35]],[[205,781],[15,4]],[[220,785],[7,-29]],[[227,756],[-14,-6]],[[213,750],[-8,31]],[[227,1268],[44,7]],[[271,1275],[30,6]],[[301,1281],[15,-26]],[[316,1255],[-62,-62]],[[213,1211],[14,57]],[[247,1065],[32,36]],[[320,1100],[10,-21]],[[293,1055],[-52,1]],[[241,1056],[6,9]],[[241,1056],[-11,-26]],[[230,1030],[-57,-18]],[[173,1012],[-8,131]],[[165,1143],[64,45]],[[226,1144],[21,-79]],[[293,878],[-12,10]],[[281,888],[-9,78]],[[272,966],[20,50]],[[292,1016],[24,15]],[[324,1034],[205,-35]],[[529,999],[145,-93]],[[674,906],[83,-96]],[[757,810],[-370,5]],[[387,815],[-94,63]],[[350,1058],[131,-2]],[[481,1056],[48,-57]],[[339,1110],[134,7]],[[473,1117],[8,-61]],[[292,1016],[-62,14]],[[0,233],[29,-22]],[[29,211],[123,-195]],[[152,16],[-152,217]],[[239,0],[-87,16]],[[29,211],[58,101]],[[87,312],[115,-67]],[[202,245],[37,-245]],[[102,665],[61,-94]],[[163,571],[-23,-82]],[[140,489],[-28,-114]],[[112,375],[-25,-63]],[[0,233],[102,432]],[[284,1115],[-47,30]],[[270,1180],[39,-24]],[[309,1156],[1,-18]],[[165,1143],[15,61]],[[180,1204],[33,7]],[[301,1281],[-7,19]],[[294,1300],[41,8]],[[335,1308],[16,-27]],[[351,1281],[2,-31]],[[353,1250],[-37,5]],[[277,1304],[17,-4]],[[271,1275],[6,29]],[[269,1321],[-31,18]],[[238,1339],[18,15]],[[256,1354],[16,-29]],[[268,1310],[-37,15]],[[231,1325],[7,14]],[[227,1268],[4,57]],[[277,1310],[0,-6]],[[389,1320],[-38,-39]],[[335,1308],[5,47]],[[340,1355],[49,-35]],[[180,1204],[3,163],[152,11]],[[335,1378],[-79,-24]],[[226,566],[-11,-8]],[[215,558],[-45,10]],[[170,568],[64,35]],[[234,603],[-8,-37]],[[335,1378],[5,-23]],[[353,1250],[-13,-67]],[[340,1183],[-31,-27]],[[129,789],[76,-8]],[[213,750],[-32,-32]],[[181,718],[-57,-31]],[[124,687],[5,102]],[[222,829],[-2,-44]],[[129,789],[18,110]],[[147,899],[71,-7]],[[218,892],[10,-5]],[[246,887],[35,1]],[[293,878],[-32,-10]],[[313,670],[-54,22]],[[259,692],[-78,26]],[[227,756],[86,-86]],[[387,815],[-24,-170]],[[363,645],[-50,25]],[[218,492],[-3,66]],[[226,566],[98,8]],[[324,574],[-106,-82]],[[112,375],[83,-1]],[[195,374],[7,-129]],[[234,603],[25,89]],[[363,645],[-39,-71]],[[195,374],[-29,95]],[[166,469],[52,23]],[[757,810],[-518,-810]],[[163,571],[7,-3]],[[166,469],[-26,20]],[[218,892],[54,74]],[[147,899],[26,113]],[[501,1205],[-3,54]],[[498,1259],[199,35]],[[697,1294],[-196,-89]],[[364,1250],[-11,0]],[[389,1320],[69,-45]],[[458,1275],[-94,-25]],[[494,1139],[-27,20]],[[467,1159],[34,46]],[[697,1294],[228,-312]],[[925,982],[-431,157]],[[352,1169],[-12,14]],[[364,1250],[48,-75]],[[412,1175],[-60,-6]],[[458,1275],[40,-16]],[[467,1159],[-55,16]],[[102,665],[22,22]],[[925,982],[-251,-76]],[[473,1117],[21,22]],[[352,1169],[-16,-44]]],"transform":{"scale":[0.002900599999999996,0.0024849150943396215],"translate":[35.050198,29.237060999999997]},"objects":{"jordan":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"arcs":[[0,1,2,3]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":2,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":2,"id_1":1,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AJ.KF","name_2":"Kofranjah","name_1":"Ajlun","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[4,5,6,7,8,9]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":9,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":9,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Wadi al-Sayr","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.WE","name_2":"Wadi Essier","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[10,11,12,13]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":20,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":20,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":null,"name_2":"Hariema","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[14,15,16,17]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":29,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":29,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Faqqu","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.FA","name_2":"Faqqoo'","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[18,19,20,21,22]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":6,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":6,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.NA","name_2":"Na'oor","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[23,24,25,26]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":13,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":13,"id_1":4,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":null,"name_2":"Al-Balqa","name_1":"Balqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[27,28,29,30]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":32,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":32,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Karak","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.KA","name_2":"Karak","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[31,32,33,34,-3,35]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":1,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":1,"id_1":1,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Ajlun","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AJ.AJ","name_2":"Ajloun","name_1":"Ajlun","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[36,-9,37,-21,38,39]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":3,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":3,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.AM","name_2":"Amman","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[40,41,42,43,-1,-25,44,-40]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":17,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":17,"id_1":4,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Shuna al-Janibiyya","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.BA.SJ","name_2":"Shooneh Janoobiyyeh","name_1":"Balqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[45,46,47,48,-19,49,50,51,52,53]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":4,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":4,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Jiza","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.JI","name_2":"Jizeh","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-50,-23,54,55]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":5,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":5,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Mwwqqar","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.MO","name_2":"Mowaqqar","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-22,-38,-8,56,57,-55]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":7,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":7,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.SH","name_2":"Sahab","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-49,58,-41,-39,-20]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":8,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":8,"id_1":2,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Um al-Basatin","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AM.UB","name_2":"Um El-Basatien","name_1":"Amman","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[59,60,61]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":10,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":10,"id_1":3,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Aqaba","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AQ.AQ","name_2":"Aqaba","name_1":"Aqaba","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[62,-61,63,64,65]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":11,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":11,"id_1":3,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Quwayra","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AQ.QR","name_2":"Quaira","name_1":"Aqaba","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[66,67,68,69,-64,-60,70]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":12,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":12,"id_1":3,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Wadi Araba|Gharandal","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AQ.WA","name_2":"Wadi Arabah","name_1":"Aqaba","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-5,71,-27,72,73]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":14,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":14,"id_1":4,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Ardhah|Sbaihi","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.BA.AR","name_2":"Ardhah","name_1":"Balqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[74,75,-2,-44]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":15,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":15,"id_1":4,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.BA.DA","name_2":"Dair Alla","name_1":"Balqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-37,-45,-24,-72,-10]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":16,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":16,"id_1":4,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"As-Salt","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.BA.ST","name_2":"Salt","name_1":"Balqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-34,76,77,78,79,80]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":18,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":18,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Aghwar Shamaliyyeh|Shooneh Shamaliyyeh","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.AS","name_2":"Aghwar Shamaliyyeh","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[81,-77,-33,82]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":19,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":19,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Bani Knana|Sama El-Roosan","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.BK","name_2":"Bani Kenanah","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-13,83,84,85]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":21,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":21,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.IR","name_2":"Irbid","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-12,86,87,-84]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":22,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":22,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Dair Abi Sa'id","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.KO","name_2":"Kora","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-83,-32,88,-87,-11,89]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":23,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":23,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Mazar Shamaliyyeh","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.MS","name_2":"Mazar Shamali","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[90,-79,91,92]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":24,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":24,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Ar Ramtha","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.RA","name_2":"Ramtha","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-89,-36,-76,93,94,-85,-88]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":25,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":25,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.TA","name_2":"Tayybeh","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[95,96,97,98]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":47,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":47,"id_1":11,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Bisaira","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AT.BS","name_2":"Bsaira","name_1":"Tafilah","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-90,-14,-86,-95,99,-92,-78,-82]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":26,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":26,"id_1":5,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Kofor Asad","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.IR.WS","name_2":"Wastiyyeh","name_1":"Irbid","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-26,-4,-35,-81,100,101,-73]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":27,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":27,"id_1":6,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Jerash","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.JA.JA","name_2":"Jarash","name_1":"Jarash","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[102,-31,103,104,105]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":28,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":28,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.AY","name_2":"Ayy","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[106,-28,-103,107,108,109,-18]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":30,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":30,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Mazra'a","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.MZ","name_2":"Ghour El-Mazra'ah","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-16,110,-46,111]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":31,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":31,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Safi","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.SF","name_2":"Ghour Essafi","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[112,113,-104,-30,114]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":33,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":33,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Mazar al-Janubiyya","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.MJ","name_2":"Mazar Janoobi","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-115,-29,-107,-17,-112,-54,115,116]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":34,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":34,"id_1":7,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Qasr","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.KA.QA","name_2":"Qasr","name_1":"Karak","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[117,-96,118,119]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":35,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":35,"id_1":8,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Husanyniyya","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MN.HU","name_2":"Husseiniyyeh","name_1":"Ma`an","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-65,-70,120,121]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":36,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":36,"id_1":8,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Ayi","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MN.IE","name_2":"Iel","name_1":"Ma`an","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-119,-99,122,-113,-117,123]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":48,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":48,"id_1":11,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Hasa","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AT.HE","name_2":"Hesa","name_1":"Tafilah","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-122,124,125,-120,-124,-116,-53,126,-66]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":37,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":37,"id_1":8,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MN.MN","name_2":"Ma'an","name_1":"Ma`an","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[127,-97,-118,-126,128,-68]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":38,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":38,"id_1":8,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Ash-Shibek","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MN.SB","name_2":"Shoabak","name_1":"Ma`an","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-121,-69,-129,-125]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":39,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":39,"id_1":8,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":null,"name_2":"Wadi Musa","name_1":"Ma`an","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-15,-110,129,-47,-111]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":40,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":40,"id_1":9,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MD.DB","name_2":"Dhiban","name_1":"Madaba","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-42,-59,-48,-130,-109,130]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":41,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":41,"id_1":9,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MD.MD","name_2":"Madaba","name_1":"Madaba","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[131,132,133]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":45,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":45,"id_1":10,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MA.SA","name_2":"Sabha","name_1":"Mafraq","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[134,-80,-91,135,136]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":46,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":46,"id_1":10,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Sama as-Sarhan","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MA.SS","name_2":"Sama Serhan","name_1":"Mafraq","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[137,138,-134,139,140]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":42,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":42,"id_1":10,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MA.ER","name_2":"Ar-Ruwayshid","name_1":"Mafraq","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[141,-101,-135,142,143]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":43,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":43,"id_1":10,"id_0":116,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MA.BM","name_2":"Bal'ama","name_1":"Mafraq","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-143,-137,144,-132,-139,145]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":44,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":44,"id_1":10,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Mafraq","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.MA.MA","name_2":"Mafraq","name_1":"Mafraq","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-67,146,-105,-114,-123,-98,-128]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":49,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":49,"id_1":11,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Tafila","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AT.AT","name_2":"Tafileh","name_1":"Tafilah","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[147,-51,-56,-58,148,-141]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":50,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":50,"id_1":12,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Al-Azraq","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AZ.ZQ","name_2":"Azraq","name_1":"Zarqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[149,-6,-74,-102,-142]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":51,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":51,"id_1":12,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Birin","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AZ.BR","name_2":"Bierain","name_1":"Zarqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}},{"arcs":[[-149,-57,-7,-150,-144,-146,-138]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"cartodb_id":52,"ccn_2":0,"id_2":52,"id_1":12,"id_0":116,"varname_2":"Az-Zarqa","nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Sub-Province","type_2":"Nahia","cca_2":null,"hasc_2":"JO.AZ.AZ","name_2":"Zarqa","name_1":"Zarqa","name_0":"Jordan","iso":"JOR"}}]}}}


var features = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.jordan).features;

d3.map(features, function(d) {
 // show all the properties of each feature:
 d3.map(d3.keys(d.properties), function(e) {
  console.log(e + " : " + d.properties[e]);
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/2.2.0/topojson.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.js"></script>
```

The second nested d3.map portion could be used on features (say a mouseover or label) where only one feature is being examined at a time.

If you want all properties outputted on one line, then you can try something along the lines of:

```
// loop through each feature
d3.map(features, function(d) {
    var string = "";
    // show all the properties of each feature:
    d3.map(d3.keys(d.properties), function(e) {
        string += (e + ":" + d.properties[e] + "  ");
    })
    console.log(string);
})
```

I'd cap out the character count if I included another snippet, so I hope that this allows you to get closer to your goal.